# How can I create a soft outer atmosphere that fades into space?

Tags: materials, effects

I'm creating an animation that simulates orbiting a planet. I'm having success on all fronts except for one: How can I create a soft (blurry) atmosphere that fades into space?

For static images this is easily accomplished post-render in Photoshop, but how to do it for an animation?

The outer atmosphere also needs to realistically interact with light.

I've done a lot of research and tried a lot of ideas, but no joy. I did find a 3rd-party payware solution that uses an emissive material that achieves a nice soft effect, but because the material is emissive and the animation includes the parts of the planet in shadow, I can't use it globally. Any suggestions? Thanks! Blender 3.1.2, Windows 11

[image: Example]

Comment: I think my second answer -- using a Gas Domain -- is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Try using a combination of Volume Absorption and Volume Scatter nodes into a Mix Shader, into the Volume material output. Vary the Density on the two Volume nodes.

[image]

[image]

My trivial example: [image]

As rendered in Cycles:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and for the example! It appears your solution uses Eevee, and I'm rendering in Cycles; in the latter the effect renders opaque black. I'll need to play with it to see if it's the solution I'm looking for. Thanks again.

Comment: @WilburPost I just downloaded the solution and rendered in Cycles -- looks good to me and I added that rendering to the bottom of my answer.  But it looks clear that it doesn't "fade into space".  I'm thinking you may have to use geometry nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution that appears to meet your criteria of "fading" as you render further away from the planets surface.

[image]  (after downloading be sure to *Bake* the domain).

For the planet:  Object >> Quick Effects >> Gas

I use a gas simulation that 1) only simulates for a single frame, so the atmosphere is relatively "static", 2) does not use the Scene gravity (you might add a Force object colocated with the planet sourcing the gas):

[image]

You can then play around with the material that is automatically added (*Principled Volume*).  I adjusted the Color to pure white, reduced the Density multiplier, which is based on the *density* attribute of the gas particles per voxel.

[image]

The render (here in cycles) seems to have the effect you are asking.   I would fuss with other simulation and render parameters to get more realism and thinner atmosphere.  An example might be to reduce Buoyancy Density to less than 1.0, perhaps to 0.1.

[image]